# Spring batch async step

Tags: spring-batch

I have multiple flow jobs with nested splits running in parallel and they are using shared `task executor thread pool` . 
The constraint is that each flow job will require number of available threads equals to number of nested splits. 
Is it possible to run step as non-blocking operation (my step tasklet implementation supports it) to minimize the number of threads in the pool.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "run step as non-blocking operation"? When you run two or more steps in parallel using an asynchronous task executor, they run in a asynchronous non-blocking way.

Comment: They are running on threads from the shared pool and  I can't run simultaneously 2 jobs with 10 parallel steps each with thread pool with 15 as max size, for example . Because the API does support Future <RepeatStatus> to be returned from the tasklet. On the other hand, my tasklet implementation does support non blocking NIO call. I wonder if Async nonblocking tasklet is supported and I can have 10 threads to run 20 parallel steps, for example.